# Import data from internet in Python - Problem with Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, internet-explorer

I need to take the prices of flights from one site, but i have some problems with dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

city1 = ['Belém', 'Belo Horizonte', 'Campo Grande', 'Curitiba', 'Brasília', 'Fortaleza', 'Goiânia', 'Porto Alegre']
city1cod = ['BEL.', 'CNF.', 'CGR.', 'CWB.', 'BSB.', 'FOR.', 'GYN.', 'POA.']

city2 = ['Rio de Janeiro', 'Florianópolis', 'Curitiba', 'São Paulo', 'Salvador', 'Natal', 'Goiânia', 'Fortaleza']
city2cod = ['/m/06gmr.', 'FLN.', 'CWB.', '/m/022pfm.', 'SSA.', 'NAT.', 'GYN.', 'FOR.']

date = ('2019-07-20*', '2019-07-28')


urls = [] 

for c1 in city1cod:
    for c2 in city2cod:

      if c1 != c2:

           url1 = 'https://www.xxxddd.com/voos=' + c1 + c2 + date[0] + c2 + c1 + date[1] + ';c:USD;e:1;sd:1;t:f'
            urls.append(url1)


def scrape (url) : 

    options = Options()

    driver = 
webdriver.Chrome(r'J:\Bi\Python\chromedriver_win329\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options) 
    driver.implicitly_wait(100)

    driver.get(str(url))

    driver.set_script_timeout(10000)
    driver.implicitly_wait(300)


     list = []

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'gws-flights-results__times-row')))


   for a in driver.find_elements_by_class_name(r'gws-flights-results__times-row'):
        a = a.text
        driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        list.append(a)
        driver.implicitly_wait(20)

    df1 =  pd.DataFrame({'Hora': list})

    list = []
    for a in driver.find_elements_by_class_name(r'gws-flights-results__airports'):
        driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        a = a.text
        list.append(a)

    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Trajeto': list})    


    df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5], axis='columns')


  driver.close()

    return df

dffinal = pd.DataFrame([])

contagem = 0
for url1 in urls :
    try:
        df3 = scrape(url1)
        dffinal = pd.concat([dffinal, df3])
        contagem += 1
        print(int(contagem/122*100) + "% pronto!")
    except:
        pass

dffinal = dffinal.reset_index(drop=True)
print(dffinal)


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('J:/Eco/Passagens/outpassagens1.xlsx')
dffinal.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

When I do this, i have some problem with dataframe empty:

> J:/Eco/database/Bianca/Base/coleta_passagens.py:50: DeprecationWarning: use
>   options instead of chrome_options   driver =
>   webdriver.Chrome(r'J:\Bi\Python\chromedriver_win329\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options,
>   chrome_options=options) Empty DataFrame Columns: [] Index: []

Comment: You have the problem in Chrome or IE? And according to the output, it says chrome_options is deprecated, try to use options instead of chrome_option.

Comment: don't swallow the exception and you will see what the problem is (also, remove all your implicit waits, and do what the deprecation message suggests)